# java rmid exception : timeout creating child process

Tags: java

We are using java 7 rmid. And while launching commands on the rmid process, the following exception occurs.

```
java.rmi.activation.ActivateFailedException: activation failed; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.activation.ActivationException: timeout creating child process
at sun.rmi.server.ActivatableRef.activate(ActivatableRef.java:303)
at sun.rmi.server.ActivatableRef.invoke(ActivatableRef.java:132)
at deshaw.smart.commandproxy.server.ActivatableComputeEngine_Stub.execute(Unknown Source)
at deshaw.moss.util.ScriptExecutor$1.run(ScriptExecutor.java:403)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Has anybody else faced similar issues?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Comment: Could it be related to java 7 upgrade by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: It was because of a typo in the rmid startup command. Missed a 'M' while specifying the memory for rmid process.